# changing lapply function to for loop

Tags: r, apply

How can I change this `lapply` to `for` loop:

```
subsignals <- lapply(c(peakind$freqindex, midindex+1), function(x){
  upperind <- x
  fsub <- f
  notnullind <- ((fsub$freqindex >= lowerind
                  & fsub$freqindex < upperind)
                 |
                   (fsub$freqindex >  (lindex - upperind + 2)
                    & fsub$freqindex <= (lindex - lowerind + 2)))


  fsub[!notnullind,"coef"] <- 0
  lowerind <<- upperind
  Re(fft(fsub$coef, inverse=TRUE)/length(fsub$coef))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, this is not tested as your problem is not currently reproducible without additional data.  The key here is to reconstitute what used to be the `x` value supplied to the function.  We do this by explicitly creating the vector of values you want to loop through (`loop.vec`), and then for each iteration through the loop, assign a value from that vector to `upperind` (first line in the for loop).

```
f <- # NEED TO ASSIGN f HERE
midindex <- # NEED TO ASSIGN midindex HERE
lindex <- # NEED TO ASSIGN
loop.vec <- c(peakind$freqindex, midindex+1))
subsignals <- vector("list", length(loop.vec))  # pre-allocate
lowerind <- loop.vec[[1]] # I'M GUESSING HERE

for(i in seq_along(loop.vec) {
  upperind <- loop.vec[[i]]
  fsub <- f
  notnullind <- ((fsub$freqindex >= lowerind
                  & fsub$freqindex < upperind)
                 |
                   (fsub$freqindex >  (lindex - upperind + 2)
                    & fsub$freqindex <= (lindex - lowerind + 2)))


  fsub[!notnullind,"coef"] <- 0
  lowerind <- upperind
  subsignals[[i]] <- Re(fft(fsub$coef, inverse=TRUE)/length(fsub$coef))
}
```

Also, since we are no longer executing the code inside a function, we don't need to do the `<<-` global assignment anymore as the environment of a for loop persists between iterations.